How can I delete this Devexpress button?
Hope you can help me with this one! I'll appreciate it very much!
This is my first time using Devexpress, and I'm familiarizing myself with all it's properties and things, and I'm trying to delete this button on the photo that right now does nothing and is in every row of my grid, or more exactly, in the detail view of the grid (I'm using a master-detail association to open a card view when clicking on each row of the grid). This button is one I got when I added a grid object to a new proyect, so I assume is some default thing from the grid.

I don't know if theres a property that I can change or something similar. I deleted the filter button that comes along with this one succesfully with a specific property, but there's no info (or I can't find it) about this other button.
Thanks in advance!
